# Is there a way to make edited Studio Lights the default setting in Blender 3.0?

Tags: customization

I'm in the process of transitioning from Blender 2.79 to Blender 3.0, and I've been messing with the Studio Lights (Preferences > Lights > Studio Lights) and made it as close to 2.79 as I possibly could. The problem is, every time I relaunch Blender 3.0, my changes are disabled, and I have to reenable them every launch. So, is there a way to make my changes permanent? Whether it's overriding the default files or just making it stay enabled, I'm all ears. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Set everything up to your liking and then use File > Defaults > Save Startup File. On reflection they should have been saved automatically if you have Automatically save Preferences checked under the bottom-left hamburger icon on the Preferences dialog.